Issue with Adding sqflite or any backage depend on it to Flutter Project
enter image description hereI'm working on a Flutter project and trying to integrate sqflite package for SQLite database operations. I've added the dependencie to my pubspec.yaml file, but I'm encountering an error when I try to use it. when i try to make remove it the app run correctly.
my flutter is up to date so i try reinstall flutter sdk again and still not solved

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

try flutter pub upgrade first
